# Is next/image caching supported on Azure Static Web App?

Tags: next.js, azure-static-web-app, nextjs-image

I am using next/image to show images on Next JS web app using `<Image>` tag and everything is working normally: the image is scaled to the proper size, in the proper optimized format (AVIF/WebP), but the image takes ages to load, being stalled by the server response which could take up to 16 seconds in production (regardless of the original image size and format). When checking the network tab in dev tools, with cache disabled, I see the header x-next-cache with value "MISS" with most of the requests. It means that the image is not being served from the server's cache. I am deploying the site on Azure Static Web App. I am using "next": "13.4.10". My page does not use SSR, it's all static. I have also added "sharp": "^0.32.3" to the dependencies, and apparently it's doing its job scaling and optimizing images on request.

In development the header is always "STALE" which I think is by design.

I read the documentation and other questions countless times, and saw the example code, and it's not different from what I am doing.

The thing is, when I tried deploying the project on Vercel, the cache is always HIT (after the first time) which is expected. Is this issue related to Azure Static Web App, or do I miss something?

Here is my code:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import myImage from '@/public/img/image1.jpg';

...

export const MySection = () => {

  return (
    <section>
        <Image
          src={myImage}
          alt=""
          fill
          priority
          placeholder={"blur"}
          sizes="100vw"
          style={{
            objectFit: "cover",
            objectPosition: "center",
          }}
        />
    </section>
  );
};
```

In next.config.js, I had some configurations, but removing those also made no difference:

```
images: {
    formats: ["image/avif", "image/webp"],
    deviceSizes: [600, 900, 1200, 1536, 1920],
}
```